# getElementById in javascript constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor

I have a question about the attached code snippet. What do you think about the element selection. I selected the element by id, but twice. I looking for a solution, when I able to initialize my variable to an element object.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function Navigation(){

    stepValue = 50;
    horizontalPosition = 0;
    verticalPosition = 0;

    this.step = function(direction){
        if(direction=="left"){
            horizontalStep(horizontalPosition-=stepValue);
        } else if(direction=="right"){
            horizontalStep(horizontalPosition+=stepValue);
        } else if(direction=="up"){
            verticalStep(verticalPosition-=stepValue);
        } else if(direction=="down"){
            verticalStep(verticalPosition+=stepValue);
        }
    }

    horizontalStep = function(value){
        document.getElementById('slider').style.left=horizontalPosition;
    }

    verticalStep = function(value){
        document.getElementById('slider').style.top=verticalPosition;
    }
}


Navigation.prototype = {
    left: function(){
        this.step("left");  
    },
    right: function(){
        this.step("right");
    },
    up: function(){
        this.step("up");
    },
    down: function(){
        this.step("down");
    }
}

var Nav = new Navigation();


</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="Nav.left()" id="left"  value="Left" />
<input type="button" onclick="Nav.right()" id="right" value="Right" />
<input type="button" onclick="Nav.up()" id="up"  value="Up" />
<input type="button" onclick="Nav.down()" id="down" value="Down" />
<div id="slider" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background: #ccc000; position: relative;">hello</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Possible to initialize the variable in the constructor, without window onload like this (item variable):

```
   function Navigation(){
     stepValue = 50;
     horizontalPosition = 0;
     verticalPosition = 0;
     item = document.getElementById("slider");
     ....
```

If it impossible I will combine with jquery. I think it will be a solution.

Thank you answers and opinion!

Tibi

Comment: Syntax-wise nothing prevents you from writing that. Execution wise, if the DOM has not yet loaded a `#slider` object, your `item` var will remain undefined.

Comment: BTW, you are calling function with argument `value` but it is not used in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the `<script></script>` just before the end of body tag in HTML like this : :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
</body>

<!-- put all your html here before the script tag -->

<script>
    //place your script here
</script>
</body>
<html>
```

This will ensure that all you DOM is already loaded in the memory before the script got executed.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
function Navigation() {
    var item = document.getElementById('slider');
    // ...
}

var Nav = null;
$(function () {
    Nav = new Navigation();
});
```

so that the code doesn't run until the DOM is ready and the `#slider` element exists.  Only at that point can you fetch it from the DOM and save it in a variable.